# spring multiple multipart request file upload - multipart size is 0

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I have been trying to upload files using spring multipart request . 
My controller is like :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadDocuments")
    @ResponseBody
    public  String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest       request,HttpServletResponse response) {                 

        System.out.println("reached here.. ");
        List<MultipartFile> files = request.getFiles("files");
        System.out.println(files.size()+"size of the multipart file");
```

I am using ajax call to load my files. and files are getting added like this :

```
 var files = [];
 files.push($('#files')[0].files[0]);
```

I dont know what I am missing. Struggling to get the array of files in the service. Please help.

My client side code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    var formData = new FormData();

                    var files = [];
                    files.push($('#files')[0].files[0]);
                    files.push($('#files')[0].files[1]);
                    formData.append('files', files);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8085/MyWar/services/uploadDocuments',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: formData,
                        timeout: 45000,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        maxFileSize: 2097152,
                        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                            alert('ERROR');
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('SUCCESS');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="file" id="files" multiple=""/>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way at last. I was trying to send multiple files as

```
var files = [];
            files.push($('#files')[0].files[0]);
            files.push($('#files')[0].files[1]);
            formData.append('files', files);
```

the problem with this method is that , the resulting file array which gets added with the name 'files' is not received at the controller side. 
Some interesting questions and sites related to this :
1. http://dhruba.name/2008/12/27/implementing-single-and-multiple-file-multipart-uploads-using-spring-25/ 
2. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/

Now, I changed the parameter sent from client side like :

```
 formData.append('files_1', files[0]);
 formData.append('files_2', files[1]);
```

i.e instead of a file array, sending multiple files and appending to form data helped me.